# How can I use the CDate function in an MSAccess object

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to update a control (in date format) to the current date and ensure that it's format is solid (e.g. not containing hours and seconds).  In this example, i am trying to update the control 'AsOfDateL1'. The error message I am getting is Runtime error '6' Overflow

```
AsOfDateL1 = CDate(Format((Now()), yyyy / mm / dd))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the date format with double quotes if you plan to use `Format` like that.

```
AsOfDateL1 = CDate(Format((Now()), "yyyy/mm/dd"))
```

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua: Great, please mark my answer as the accepted answer to let future viewers know that this worked for you.

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua You could also just use the `Date()` function instead of the `Now()` function and not have to use `Format` and `CDate` at all.

Comment: Thanks Gord.  I knew that.  It just doesnt come that natural to me!